# How do you add another dataframe to pandas hdf5

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

```
db = pd.HDFStore("database.h5")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
db.put("A1", df, format = 'table', data_columns = True)
db["A1"]

    Col1    Col2    Col3
0   1.036201    -0.395399   -0.741962
1   0.233349    -0.733992   0.754594

db.close()
```

Now I want to add another dataframe that is unrelated (in **another file** at a later stage, so I have to close db for now):

```
db = pd.read_hdf("database.h5")
db.put("A3", newdf, format='table', data_columns=True)
```

I get the error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'put'` and I see that db is actually a dataframe:

```
db
    Col1    Col2    Col3
0   1.036201    -0.395399   -0.741962
1   0.233349    -0.733992   0.75459
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default mode is `a`ppend, so you could just open the file the same way and add more dataFrames as needed:

```
db = pd.HDFStore("database.h5", 'a')  # open existing store
db.put("A3", newdf, format='table', data_columns=True)
db.close()
```